# Tkinter display class list text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tokenize

I have the following piece of code: I am trying to get the text from function showText to actually appear in the window

```
from tkinter import *
import wikipedia
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
import time

subject = wikipedia.page("Assembly language")
#print(p.url)
#print(p.title)
plain_text = subject.content
plain_text_words = word_tokenize(plain_text)



class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master= None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title('Test')

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand =1)

        quitButton = Button(self, text = 'Exit', command=self.client_exit)

        quitButton.place(x=500, y=300)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        file = Menu(menu)

        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)
        file.add_command(label='Run', command=self.showText)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.client_exit)

        help_menu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=help_menu)
        help_menu.add_command(label='About')


    def showText(self):
        for i in range (0, len(plain_text_words)):
            words = [i]
            time.sleep(3)
            words.pack()


    def client_exit(self):
        exit()


root = Tk()

w = 600 # width of the window
h = 370 # height of the window

# get screen width and height
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() 
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)


root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
```

The piece that's causing me grief is this bit:

```
def showText(self):
        for i in range (0, len(plain_text_words)):
            words = [i]
            time.sleep(3)
            words.pack()
```

I am trying to get each piece of text to show as individual words on the window but no matter how I try and do it, I get an error. I have tried various things such as converting to lists etc Hoping someone can help..

PS: You will need to download the nltk dataset before this code will run

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your pack function misses the brackets.
Second, your var `words` is a list. Not a tkinter widget. You can only pack tkinter widgets.

To solve it you need to add the list to a text widget for example.

Comment: Hi @PythonAmateur742 The words are initially a class list that returns a string. So, I am taking that string and populating it in a list words = [] I thought I was then adding this to a widget by passing the list to pack. How then can this be passed?